# Replacing img tag with preg_replace and regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I do not understand regular expressions. I need to change an img tag formatted in this manner: `<img class="special-class" (then custom srcs and whatever) />`. I figure preg_replace would do the job or would there be something more effective?

I just need the regular expression way to search for the full img tag with that first class so i can replace it with another string saved as $buzz

Comment: Change how? Into what? Replace something by something? Not very clear, you are!

Comment: with php preg_replace( $replace_this , $with_this , $html_string ) i need the $replace_this

Comment: Yeah... That's the one thing that was clear. Read the questions in my comment: how, what, something something.

Comment: please extend your question with what you'd like to achieve

Comment: You should consider using a parser instead of dealing with regular expressions. Beware of the pony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **match** a full img tag (with valid html and no unquoted `>` in there):

```
preg_match('#<img([^>]+)>#i', $html, $match);
```

Don't know what else you want...

`$match` will contain the full  in `[0]` and the attributes (as string) in `[1]`.

If you want to match the class attribute:

```
preg_match('#class="([^"])"#i', $html, $match);
```

**edit**
Huh this might work:

```
preg_replace('#<img[^>]+class="[^"]*replace[^"]*"[^>]*>#', '', $html);
```

If I input:

```
<img src="oele" class="boele" />
<img src="boele" />
<img src class="replace boele">
```

it only replaces the last img and leaves the rest untouched.

Regex rules!

Comment: Replace the image? Remove the full img tag? That's near to impossible with regex. HTML isn't a regexable format.

Comment: oh.. theres no way to do like '<img class="special-class" ([^>])>#i' ?

Comment: You can do that, but is `class` always the first attribute and does it always contain only that one class? I edited my answer with a better (?) solution.

Comment: What part of that code is "near to impossible" specifically? Editing HTML in my text editor seems to work fine most of the time. What's the problem with pattern matching the very same text? Or is this to satisfy the dated joke page and people confusing parsing with matching again?

Comment: HTML is very difficult to parse. Ask any browser. In my regex I'm making a few assumptions that aren't necessarily true: 1) attributes are quoted with a double quote 2) there are no `<` or `>` within a tag ever 3) the tag name is lowercase (but that's easy) That's why HTML doesn't have conventional format definition, but instead a DTD. Anyway. Regex rules!

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for a Javascript solution (think of jQuery). If you would like I can be of help with that

Comment: i cant do that, it needs to be server side

Comment: sorry, but you didn't mentioned this in your question :)

Comment: no problem, its just giving -1 is quite troublesome, cuz I'm very new to stackoverflow and I need some score ;)

Comment: i didnt do that i dont think i even have enough points to do that ive been trying to vote people up

Comment: Didn't downvote. But very tempted. One-liners aren't actually [good] answers. Please add a jQuery rewrite example code snippet at least, to turn this into an answer.

Comment: dont be a hater mario he offered further help haha

Comment: ok mario thanks for the hint, I will keep it in mind for future posts